# Does Entity Framework 4.1 have a meta-model?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

In LINQ to SQL you can inspect the underlying meta-model of a data context via its Mapping property.

Is there an equivalent or close-enough pattern in EF Code First for inspecting or manipulating model configuration, given a DbContext instance?

I know you can use the Fluent API to configure the mappings up front, but I'm talking about general inspection of a model from outside code using an API, without needing to have object instances to work with (other than the DbContext, of course).

Comment: why would you want to go through the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbContext` itself doesn't provide access to meta model. You must convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` by using:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

After that you can access `objectContext.MetadataWorkspace` but the workspace itself was not designed for direct usage - API is highly unfriendly and it is read only.

Comment: Read-only is OK - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!